# VBA + SQL Server (ADODB) fetching not null data returning null

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have this disturbing issue.
The field `MSP_WEB_WORK.WWORK_VALUE` is a `DECIMAL`.

When I query directly the database, everything is ok:

```
select w.WWORK_START AS work_date, 
     w.WWORK_FINISH AS finish_date, 
     p.PROJ_NAME as Project, 
     a.TASK_NAME as Task, 
     a.WASSN_COMMENTS as Comment, 
     w.WWORK_VALUE / 60000 as work, 
     r.RES_NAME as Resource, 
     r.WRES_ID as resource_id, 
     datediff(d,w.wwork_start,w.wwork_finish)+1 AS work_days 
 from SP_WEB_RESOURCES r, 
     MSP_WEB_ASSIGNMENTS a, 
     MSP_WEB_PROJECTS p, 
     MSP_WEB_WORK w 
 where w.WWORK_TYPE = 1 
   and w.WASSN_ID = a.WASSN_ID 
   and a.WPROJ_ID = p.WPROJ_ID 
   and a.WRES_ID = r.WRES_ID 
   and w.WWORK_FINISH between '2014-01-01' and '2014-02-01' 
   and w.WWORK_VALUE > 0
```

The problem is when I try to get this same data within VBA to populate an Excel Sheet:

```
queryPointed = "select w.WWORK_START AS work_date," & _
    " w.WWORK_FINISH AS finish_date," & _
    " p.PROJ_NAME as Project," & _
    " a.TASK_NAME as Task," & _
    " a.WASSN_COMMENTS as Comment," & _
    " w.WWORK_VALUE / 60000 as work," & _
    " r.RES_NAME as Resource," & _
    " r.WRES_ID as resource_id," & _
    " datediff(d,w.wwork_start,w.wwork_finish)+1 AS work_days" & _
" from MSP_WEB_RESOURCES r," & _
     "MSP_WEB_ASSIGNMENTS a," & _
     "MSP_WEB_PROJECTS p," & _
     "MSP_WEB_WORK w" & _
" where w.WWORK_TYPE = 1" & _
  " and w.WASSN_ID = a.WASSN_ID" & _
  " and a.WPROJ_ID = p.WPROJ_ID" & _
  " and a.WRES_ID = r.WRES_ID" & _
  " and w.WWORK_FINISH between '" & _
    Format(startDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' and '" & Format(endDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'" & _
  " and w.WWORK_VALUE > 0"

  queryPointed = queryPointed & " order by finish_date"

    ' Seleciona a planilha com os relatórios
    Worksheets("report").Select

    i = 6
    ' Retorna os dados do banco
    Set dbrs = getRecordset(queryPointed)

    If (dbrs.EOF = True) Then
        MsgBox "A busca ao banco de dados não retornou resultados para Rework e Trip!" & vbNewLine & "Verifique o campo Task Type no cronograma publicado.", vbExclamation, "Busca de Rework e Trip"
    Else
        Do While Not dbrs.EOF
            Worksheets("report").Cells(i, 1) = dbrs.Fields("Resource").Value
            Worksheets("report").Cells(i, 2) = dbrs.Fields("finish_date").Value
            Worksheets("report").Cells(i, 3) = dbrs.Fields("Project").Value
            Worksheets("report").Cells(i, 4) = dbrs.Fields("Task").Value
            Worksheets("report").Cells(i, 5) = dbrs.Fields("work").Value
            Worksheets("report").Cells(i, 6) = dbrs.Fields("Comment").Value
            i = i + 1
            dbrs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
```

All columns are correctly inserted on my sheet, but the field `work`.

When I try to display `work` field value with `MsgBox`, it shows it is empty.

What is going on?

### Edit:

For some reason I still don't understand, if I change the order of the assignments, putting `word` column first, it works just fine:

```
Worksheets("report").Cells(i, 5) = dbrs.Fields("work").Value
Worksheets("report").Cells(i, 1) = dbrs.Fields("Resource").Value
Worksheets("report").Cells(i, 2) = dbrs.Fields("finish_date").Value
Worksheets("report").Cells(i, 3) = dbrs.Fields("Project").Value
Worksheets("report").Cells(i, 4) = dbrs.Fields("Task").Value
Worksheets("report").Cells(i, 6) = dbrs.Fields("Comment").Value
```

It works, but I refuse to accept this with no explanation of why this happens.

Someone?

### Edit 2:

After some shuffling, I've found out that the problem is the `Resource` field. It has to come AFTER `work` and `Comment` fields, like this:

```
Worksheets("report").Cells(i, 2) = dbrs.Fields("finish_date").Value
Worksheets("report").Cells(i, 3) = dbrs.Fields("Project").Value
Worksheets("report").Cells(i, 4) = dbrs.Fields("Task").Value
Worksheets("report").Cells(i, 6) = dbrs.Fields("Comment").Value
Worksheets("report").Cells(i, 5) = dbrs.Fields("work").Value
Worksheets("report").Cells(i, 1) = dbrs.Fields("Resource").Value
```

Info about the `Resource`field:

- Type: nvarchar(255)
- IS_NULLABLE: no
- NULLABLE: 0

Comment: Does it stop working on the very first result from the resultSet? Is it possible that there is a `Null` value there?

Comment: No, it doesn't stop working, it just doesn't show that column, but all others are ok... By the way, the field is `NOT NULL`...

Comment: Hmmmm. That is certainly annoying. Just for kicks and giggles, have you tried removing the `/ 60000` from `w.WWORK_VALUE / 60000`? Also, have you tried adding a watch in the compiler for `dbrs.Field("work").Value`?

Comment: Yes, also gives me nothing... It seems like a problem in the way I'm iterating over the data... Could you check my `Do While` statement? This is my second day with VBA...

Comment: I don't usually handle resultSets like this. I will post what I usually do as an answer just because I can't fit it in the comments. But I'm not sure if it will answer your question or not.

Answer (score 0):

So I usually grab data from a postgreSQL, SQL Server, or Oracle database in a slightly different manner. I actually have a class I've defined that does it, but I'll try to simplify it down into one Sub. Maybe this can help you find your issue.

```
Sub grabDataAndCreateTable()
     'Make sure that you have the reference Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library enabled. For me it x.x was 2.8
     Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection, dataTable As New ADODB.Recordset, connectionString as String, userName as String, password as String
     'Sounds like you know how to find this, but just in case
     'http://www.connectionstrings.com/
     connectionString = "yourConnectionString"
     userName = "username"
     password = "1234"
     Call cn.Open connectionString, userName, password
     'Define your SELECT statement
     Dim queryPointed as String
     queryPointed = "SELECT..." 'I'm snipping your SELECT statement
     cn.CommandTimeout = 1200
     'Open up a result set with the query and connection
     dataTable.Open(queryPointed,cn)
     Dim i As Long, dataSheet as Worksheet
     Set dataSheet = thisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheet")
     'This loop dumps your headers
     For i = 0 To (dataTable.Fields.Count - 1)
          dataSheet.Cells(1, i + 1).value = dataTable.Fields(i).Name
     Next i
     'This dumps everything else
     dataSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset dataTable
     Dim tableRange As Range, newTable As ListObject
     Set tableRange = dataSheet.UsedRange
     'I like to set up a table to work with because Tables are great for vba and the end user
     Set newTable = dataSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, tableRange, , xlYes)
     newTable.Name = "TableData"
Exit Sub
```

While I use this code all the time, it is untested in this format.